# What method is there for converting from an XY to an XYZ coordinate system?

Tags: trigonometry, quaternions, spheres

I know very little about this subject but I've heard Euler's name and Quaternions suggested for solutions. If I have a base system using X and Y, and I know I can convert Cosine values (as X) into Sine Values (yielding negative Y) by deriving Cosine, or convert from Sine (as Y) to Cosine (as X) by deriving Sine, how can I get to the Z axis?

More Generally, is Trigonometry limited only to 2 dimensional circles? Are there no variants of Sine/Cos/Tan and Derivatives that work with coordinates in the VOLUME of Spheres or n-spheres and so on?

My gut tells me the imaginary plane of i could double as a Z axis but somehow this seems like it is not the answer. Bottom line, why can we convert from X to Y, but not X-> Z or Y->Z without creating a mess with the relationship of X and Y?

Comment: See [Spherical trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry).

Comment: Great Circles and Sphere Trigonometry are a variant of 2 Dimensional Coordinates on a Globe. The objects are fundamentally polygons and lack volume. Therefore, not what I am asking.

Comment: Are you asking about a generalization of the construction of sine and cosine on the unit circle onto a construnction on the unit sphere in 3D? I guess that, if possible, quaternions are the way to go, using the three imaginary units $i$, $j$, and $k$ as the three unit vectors of space.